# How to get multiple selected from input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, multi-select

I am trying to show multiple selected option of a person from selected value.
[Here](http://bit.ly/1HQ4kYl) is an example but not working.

I want to do like [this](http://bit.ly/1IuxEHl) dynamically .

Comment: Please explain more. your question should be complete with no need to external references.

Comment: I want to show all already selected value/option in multiple <select tag.

Comment: Hold down control key when click each option. The selected options turn grey.

Comment: Now see my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly you need a `trigger("chosen:updated")`

I'd updated your fiddle, you can find here [`http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/hdz8f1b6/2/`](http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/hdz8f1b6/2/). I hope it works for you.

Comment: Is it possible to show values by sort order of selected? @ebilgin

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css (for example):

```
.result-selected{color:white !important; background:blue !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

#### 1. General Events.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="GE[]" value="Brainometer>
<input type="checkbox" name="GE[]" value="Hot Seat">
<input type="checkbox" name="GE[]" value="Mind Drill> 
<input type="checkbox" name="GE[]" value="Techno Art>
<input type="checkbox" name="GE[]" value="Photography">
```

If U Want to get multiple selected option of a person from selected value Using PHP: use implode... multiple value can be store in $ge depends on what the user select...

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['GE'])){
      $ge = implode(", ",$_POST['GE']);
}else{
      $ge = "";
}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.value').val('demo 1,demo 2');

$('.chosen-select').val($('.value').val().split(',')) // set value, accepts array

$('.chosen-select').chosen();

$('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {

    values = $('.chosen-select').val();

$('.value').val(values);

}) ;
```

Comment: Is it possible to show values by sort order of selected? @vinayakj

Comment: needs to ask separate question please.. this one's been answered